# FaceboookDesktop user stays logged in after I call FaceboookDesktop.logout

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

Having the same issue as this user

[As3 Graph API Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828072/as3-graph-api-logout)

and this user
[Facebook Kiosk Logout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11998580/facebook-kiosk-logout?rq=1)

Using the AS3 FacebookDesktop SDK for an AIR desktop based kiosk application

http://facebook-actionscript-api.googlecode.com/svn/release/current/docs/com/facebook/graph/FacebookDesktop.html

I can login, upload successfully.

Additionally when I call

```
FacebookDesktop.logout(handleLogout, APP_ORIGIN)
```

the response object returned in handleLogout = success

I have also defined APP_ORIGIN to = the same url associated with my APP_ID.
and set FacebookDesktop.manageSession = false

The problem is the user stays logged in after I upload and I need to log them out automatically after each upload.

This solution suggests targeting logout.php passing the ACCESS TOKEN.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771821/log-out-from-facebook
```

But I don't have an access token, only a user ID.

Can anyone suggest a solution that works with an AIR desktop application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this thread

https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/issues/detail?id=206

> 'I had this problem and i solved using this workaround, you have to
>   download the source code of the 1.7 dist. Then open the
>   FacebookDesktop.as file and look for the logout function (not the
>   static one), then find the value 'params.next =
>   "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect/xd_proxy.php#origin="+(appOrigin?appOrigin:"")'
>   and change it to 'params.next = "http://www.facebook.com/"'.